# подтверждение кода Django

Tags: django

Изучаю django
Пытаюсь сделать заполнение базы данных пользователей через форму. С этим вроде как, справился все работает. Хочу попробовать сделать минимальную защиту от спама.
Чтобы на почту приходил код который надо будет ввести и при совпадении значение поле в модели verification = models.BooleanField(default=False) менялось на True.
вот собственно код
views.py

```
def generate_code():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(10000,99999))


def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        code = generate_code()
        subject = 'код подтверждения' 
        message = code
        send_mail(subject, message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['test@mail.ru'], 
        fail_silently=False)
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Сохранение формы
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/endreg/")

    else:
         form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})
```

в принципе код приходит
но никак не могу придумать как сделать его проверку
и изменить значение поля на True если код верный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сохранять код в базе, например. Создаете отдельную табличку с полями code и user_id (ForeignKey в терминах джанги) и хендлер в который передается этот код. В хендлере выбираем из таблички пользователя по переданному коду и выставляем verification = True

Для пущей лучшести вместо базы данных можно использовать redis с тем же алгоритмом.

Comment: а можете подсказать как передать код в поле code таблицы?
если можно с примером

Comment: В комментарии сложно приводить пример. В общем, для простоты можно сделать еще одну форму. 

Второй вариант - присылать линку с кодом вида https://link.to.your.project/validate?code=XXXX где XXXX это будет ваш код. Геренировать ее стоит через urllib.urlencode 

Далее создаете новый view и прописываете его в urlconf. Как это сделать написано [в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#view). В самом view в методе get будет параметр request, из него и достаете код как то так code = request.GET.get('code'). Ну а дальше ищете в базе его

Comment: спасибо, буду разбиратьсяя вопрос такой еще 
на сколько такая запись будет корректной?
Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],phone=request.POST['phone'],code=user_code)
вроде сохраняет и бд и то что вводится в форме и код который генерируется рандомно
при этом код что пришел на почту такой же как и записан в бд.
дальше же можно по сути создать еще одну форму с вводам кода пользователся
и написать views которая будет проверять введенный код из формы с тем что в бд и сравнивать их
и если они совпадают значение verification = True ?

Comment: Вполне корректная, можно и так сделать. Проблема только в том, что у вас в базе будет куча лишней информации в таблице пользователей. Я же не зря сказал, что лучше использовать redis для подобных действий, там можно не просто удалить код после использования, но и назначить таймаут после которого код удалится, то есть не надо будет хранить одноразовую информацию в течении жизни сервиса. Если у вас для кодов будет отдельная табличка - это будет потом легко переделать, а удалять колонку из базы достаточно долгий процесс при большом числе записей.

Comment: и последний вопрос, если можно. Сделал форму ввода кода, читаю что в него вводят  с помощью get 
code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
но не совсем понимаю как мне сделать выборку полей code из модели Registration , чтобы сравнить введенное с формы значение с значением в бд и изменить статус в True в этой записи если такое есть.
Спасибо, за уделенное время вы мне помогли разобраться с некоторыми моментами, при много благодарен

Comment: Получить объект можно вот так user = Registration.objects.get(code=code_use), если объекта нет, то будет эксепшн DoesNotExists Дальше просто user.validated = True и user.save()

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!
вы мне очень помогли, побольше бы таких людей, которые помогают новичкам разбираться.